# how access current and focused window in android adb

Tags: adb, dumpsys

I am using Android API 30 adb

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows
```

but it is not showing
mCurrentFocused and mFocused app

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

dumpsys window | grep -E "mCurrentFocus

Comment: print(device.shell('dumpsys window | grep -E "mCurrentFocus"'))

Comment: It's best to add additional information to your original answer rather than in comments. Many users focus on answers without reading the comments and may miss the additional information.